# Get output of shell command in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, shell, command, nstask

I've read solutions for doing this using NSTask: they all look very very long... So I managed to do the exact same thing using this code (which gets both standard output and standard error):

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
[task setArguments:@[ @"-c", @"aCommand"]];
NSString *stringToRemove = [task description];
[task launch];
NSString *output = [[task description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stringToRemove withString:@""];
```

Are there any drawbacks using this solution? Is there a shorter way to filter the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any drawbacks using this solution? Is there a shorter way to
>   filter the output?

Yes, many drawbacks.  You are relying on an implementation detail that `description` will magically return the task's command line and output.   That is not claimed by the documentation nor is `description` really acceptable to use beyond debugging/logging.

I.e. that code only works by convenience.

But that code isn't really working.  If the command you were to run never exits or takes a while to run or produces a massive amount of output, then that code is likely to not actually grab any of the output at all or to spew truncated output.

There is a reason why the examples that use `NSTask` tend to be a bit lengthy.   Managing I/O between processes is actually quite hard and there are a lot of different options that need to be taken into account.

Comment: Does [task waitUntilExit] avoid the problem of getting the complete output of a long lasting command?

Comment: Nope;  `waitUntilExit` will ensure all output has been generated, but you still need an `NSPipe` or `NSFileHandle` to consume the output and, likely, doing so with something like `readInBackgroundAndNotify:`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to run a command and wait for it to exit (for example to grab information from a shell command in a CLI application), you can use the following (ARC enabled):

```objectivec
    // Start the task with path and arguments.
    NSTask* task = [NSTask new];
    [task setExecutableURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/task"]];
    [task setArguments:@[@"your", @"arguments", @"here"]];

    // Intercept the standard output of the process.
    NSPipe* output = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:output];

    // Launch and wait until finished.
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];

    // Read all data from standard output as NSData.
    NSData* resultData = [[output fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
    
    // Convert NSData to string (could be combined with above when ARC used).
    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This doesn't seem unreasonable in length (and could probably be shortened, though I left this in for readability), and if you're using this often you could abstract it into a function.

I also noticed that, as you don't redirect the output in your code, it would also print the output to the console, which might be unintended.